# PHP record not adding in

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I've recently created and added a feature to add a brand into my database. However, whenever I press the add button, it doesn't do anything or show the messages from the script tag, not to mention adding the record into my database. I have tried to debug it myself but to no avail. I expected for at least some error messages to appear, but nothing was showing. Any help would be appreciated. The code below is the PHP code.

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['addBtn'])){
        $brand = $_POST['brand'];
        $session = $_SESSION['username'];
        //$date = date('Y-m-j H:i:s', time());
        $query = "INSERT INTO brand(brand,editor) VALUES ('".$brand."','".$session."')";    
            if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)){
                echo "<script>
                        alert('Successfully Added Brand');
                        window.location.href='brand.php';
                    </script>";
            }else{
                echo "<script>
                        alert('Failed to Add Brand');
                        window.location.href='brand.php';
                    </script>";
            }   
        }

 ?>
```

And This is the HTML code:

```
    <div class="container">
         <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                <table  id="tabledata" class=" table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">

                    <tr class="bg-dark text-white text-center">

                        <td> Brand </td>
                        <td>        
                        <input type="text" name="brand" placeholder="Brand" required>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <button name="addBtn" id="addBtn" type="submit" class="btn-primary btn"> Add </button></td>
                    </tr >
                </table>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Thank You.

Comment: How do you submit the form? using Ajax or there is a `form` tag? Is form target set correctly?

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. Parameterize your query. Also check the result of your query and use error reporting. Do you start your session?

Comment: I think it doesn't do anything, because you do not submit the value at all. There is not form tag with an action, neither did you show the use of AJAX.

Comment: @heh Were you able to solve your issue? Please mark an answer as the solution by clicking the green checkmark and consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort your SQL Injection issues out, but the actual issue is because your button is not contained within a form... So what is it submitting?

Quick fix:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="container">
         <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                <table  id="tabledata" class=" table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">

                    <tr class="bg-dark text-white text-center">

                        <td> Brand </td>
                        <td>        
                        <input type="text" name="brand" placeholder="Brand" required>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <button name="addBtn" id="addBtn" type="submit" class="btn-primary btn"> Add </button></td>
                    </tr >
                </table>
         </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Having the submit button inside a form will ensure it submits the aforementioned form.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing your `<input>` and `<button>` elements in a `<form>` tag. Then add an `action` in the `<form>` tag to the function that is to process the form. Since you're using the POST HTTP method, I mean something like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{link-to-the-script-or-function-to-process-the-form}">..</form>
```

You can enclose your HTML in this.